# Is it possible to find destination content of a DNS record?

Tags: dns, subdomain, nslookup, cname

Suppose that there are below 2 records for domain `example.com` :

| Type | Name | Content (Destination) | SubDomain URL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | sub1 | ***185.185.185.185*** | sub1.example.com |
| CNAME | sub2 | ***xxx.another-example.com*** | sub2.example.com |

Is it possible to get **Content (Destination)** of record for subdomains via DNS Lookup Tools?

**EDIT**:

To clarify my question, I added a real case as below. It is one of the DNS records on my domain, which point a subdomain of mine to another webpage on 000webhost.com:

| Type | Name | Content (Destination) | SubDomain URL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| CNAME | ppp1 | testmypageeasy.000webhostapp.com | ppp1.tradecryptoforme.com |

I want to know if other people can figure out the destination of the record (in this case, `testmypageeasy.000webhostapp.com`)?

Comment: [DNS Lookup](https://dnschecker.org/all-dns-records-of-domain.php) will list all records. Is that the question?

Comment: @harrymc No, it can't show the content (target) of a CNAME record .

Comment: You need issue two queries by definition one to get cname rr, second to resolve cname value

Comment: Do you have an example site where DNS Lookup will fail for CNAME?

Comment: @harrymc I added real example.

Comment: I have tested the DNS info returned by half-dozen DNS analyzing tools and have found no correspondence between `testmypageeasy.000webhostapp.com` and `ppp1.tradecryptoforme.com`, as regarding IP, hosting etc. I used 3-4 sub-domain searching tools on `testmypageeasy.000webhostapp.com` and have not found `ppp1.tradecryptoforme.com`. I think you're well-hidden, but it's difficult to give a negative answer like this.

Comment: @harrymc Acc. to the comment by user1686 it is because of "Cloudflare".  I can't test other providers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, just make a regular DNS query and you will get the corresponding value.

```
$ dig www.example.com -t A

;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.example.com.            86398   IN   A       93.184.216.34
```

This also applies when querying a domain name that has a CNAME, although in that case it depends on what record type your query is asking for. If you're querying for `CNAME`, then you will always get *just* the CNAME:

```
$ dig www.linode.com -t cname @1.1.1.1

;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.linode.com.               271   IN   CNAME   linode.com.edgekey.net.
```

If you're querying for any other type, then you will still get the CNAME *and* the target record (if the server knows it – in this example the 1.1.1.1 server will resolve it recursively, but if it's a non-recursive server and the target belongs to another server, then you still get just the CNAME):

```
$ dig www.linode.com -t a @1.1.1.1

;; ANSWER SECTION:
www.linode.com.               294   IN   CNAME   linode.com.edgekey.net.
linode.com.edgekey.net.     21594   IN   CNAME   e26254.dsca.akamaiedge.net.
e26254.dsca.akamaiedge.net.    14   IN   A       87.245.209.222
e26254.dsca.akamaiedge.net.    14   IN   A       87.245.209.208
```

> To clear my question, I want to know the other people can figure out my records have what contents (in this case, 185.185.185.185 and xxx.another-example.com)?

Generally, yes, they can. In fact, doing so is the literally the purpose of DNS – practically the only thing that a DNS server does is answer client queries about what contents your DNS records have.

Your website traffic is not relayed through your domain or through DNS servers – clients *must* know the contents of DNS records so that they could connect to the appropriate server.

(The only exception to this is the Cloudflare CDN, whose dashboard *looks* exactly like a DNS record table but is slightly more than that. Enabling the CDN proxy feature for a particular subdomain causes Cloudflare to *remove* that subdomain's A/AAAA record contents from DNS and to publish the CDN's own addresses in its place, therefore making the actual DNS contents different from what you've entered. Even then, though, clients can still see what *was* published to DNS.)

Comment: this is don't show the target. Please write your solution based on my example table. I wonder we can find content of records (in my example: 185.185.185.185 and xxx.another-example.com)?

Comment: Yes – once again, finding contents of records is **exactly what a DNS query does.** I showed a real-world example of a DNS query showing the contents of real-world DNS records; what is the point of changing it to a completely made-up example?

Comment: Please see the real example that I added to my question. Is there any way other people find the destination (in my example: `testmypageeasy.000webhostapp.com`)?

Comment: In your case no, it falls under the "Cloudflare exception" mentioned in the post – there _isn't_ a DNS record with the provided information, it only exists in Cloudflare's internal database but not in DNS.

Comment: Thank you for your test.

Comment: Please edit your answer to mention these exceptions available on CDNs like Cloudflare, that has security for DNS record zone. I'll accept your answer.

Comment: I've already edited the post to mention Cloudflare yesterday. I will not call it "security for DNS", as using *any* CDN which proxies your traffic involves putting that CDN's addreses in DNS – I'd rather call it "Cloudflare's control panel being misleading about what goes in DNS and what doesn't".

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The purpose of DNS is to provide an extremely scalable look-up service where one looks up a DNS name (ie a host) and gets back a record that may be another DNS name or an address record (IP address), a text record or a few others.